# Allow user access to protected page using URL token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, clearance

I am using Clearance gem for authentication. I have one page in the app to which I want to permit anyone to come provided they have a secure token in the URL / Session. They need not be users in the system.

Is this doable with Clearance. Any hints on how I should proceed. Initially I thought I should override `require_login` and `current_user`. Is that a good approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should the secure token page also allow access to people who are signed in, or must *everyone* have the secure token?

If you must have the secure token, regardless of whether you are signed in with Clearance or not, then I would avoid Clearance for this controller all-together by not calling `require_login` at all (or calling `skip_before_action :require_login` if the filter is already in your controller's inheritance tree). Then you could implement your own `before_action` that checks the token and does whatever you'd like. You could also implement your own `current_user` for this controller if desired.

If the page should also allow signed in users then I would still skip the Clearance before action and instead use something like this:

```
def require_login_or_secret_token
  unless params["super_secret_security_token"] == TOKEN
    require_login
  else
end
```

Then you'd need to override current_user to return a guest object rather than nil if you want to use `current_user` in this action/view:

```
def current_user
  super || Guest.new
end
```